# Symfony2 bundles reuse and routing

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting a personnal blog with SF2 few days ago. I'm coding my back-end paying attention to reusability.

For this moment, i have 2 bundles : `AdminBundle` and `ArticleBundle`. I write some methods into `ArticleBundle` like `addAction`, `listAction`, etc. This module also has its own routes (article/add, article/edit) defined in his `routing.yml`

When i'm in a part of my AdminBundle (ex : admin/article/add), I do this in `AdminController`:

```
public function addAction() {
    return $this->render('AdminBundle:Admin:add_article.html.twig');
}
```

and in my `add_article.html.twig` :

```
{% block admin_content %}        // Inheritance of admin view
{% render url('article_add') %}  // article_add = article/add = route in ArticleBundle
{% endblock %}
```

This part works well but after the render all is managed by `ArticleBundle` and my routing goes bad (ex : after my form submission routing is 'article/add' instead of 'admin/article/add').

So i don't know how to integrate this 2 bundles together keeping in mind that `ArticleBundle` must be reusable.

thx

Comment: Why not keep your article admin in your ArticleBundle?  Which admin bundle are you using/extending?

Comment: I'm using my own admin bundle. ok you mean have an AdminController (for example) in my ArticleBundle ?

Comment: Yeah, that would be my suggestion.  Just out of curiosity, why use your own admin bundle when there are proven solutions out there?  I've gone down the road of trying to create my own admin in the past, and ended up finding out that premade solutions already have the answers I need.  I suggest looking into SonataAdmin or or Symfony2AdminGenerator(which I use currently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set out your actions within your ArticleBundle as services which are then referenced from within your Admin or other Bundle using (for example)

```
$form = $this->get('kero_zen.article_bundle.add_action.form');
$formHandler = $this->get('kero_zen.article_bundle.add_action.handler');
```

similar to that of the controllers in FOSUserBundle.

Comment: You mean define controllers as services in ArticleBundle ?

Comment: You could do it like that with Controllers as services or you could ignore the controller completely and just use the services that you reference within the controller. To be honest it really depends how your ArticleBundle is setup.

Comment: I choose the second option (create an article service and reference it into controllers). On the other hand, "controllers as services" seems not to be a best practice according Fabien Potencier -> https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/457

Comment: The only thing I've seen on 'Controllers as Services' is http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html but I have never gone down that road for the reasons stated in that Github issue, although I saw it elsewhere.